# write.csv on a list of data frames

Tags: r

I ma trying to save a number of data frames from a list in separate directory. something is wrong with my code:

```
lapply(na_s, function (x) write.csv(na_s[[x]],file = paste('/na_s_daily/',names (na_s[x]),'.csv',sep=""), row.names = F))
```

Error code:

```
Error in na_s[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Anybody can see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please make your question reproducible ... not knowing what `na_s` is makes this difficult to resolve. (Docs on [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the input x is a number not the element of a list.
Try

```
 lapply(1:length(na_sx),  function (x) write.csv(na_s[[x]],file = paste('./na_s_daily/','na_', names (na_s[x]),'.csv',sep=""), row.names = F))
```

Note that the above will also return a list of the data frames. So if you just need to save each element of the list as a data frame in your directory just do

```
for(x in 1:length(na_s)){
   write.csv(na_s[[x]],file = paste('./na_s_daily/','na_',names (na_s[x]),'.csv',sep=""), row.names = F)
}
```

Comment: I dont think that this solves my problem, and apply needs and argument to be passed on which object some function will be applied. which is a list `na_s`

Comment: @m_c glad it worked! I updated the for loop too, if you just need to save each element. Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: sounds, nice. you just need to fix  the first answer, 1:N does not really work. :)

Comment: @m_c if N = length(na_sx) then it works, but I changed it anyways as it looks nicer.

Comment: if I use 1:N, it gives me an error, because it sees it as object, which is not existing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the names of the list, I would suggest using `mapply`.  You also need to be sure the output directory exists before you use it, else you'll receive an error. I also changed `paste` to `paste0` (which is `paste(x, sep = "")`).

```
na_s <- list("one" = mtcars, "two" = mtcars, "three" = mtcars)

mapply(function (x,y) write.csv(x, file = paste0('./na_s_daily/', y, '.csv'), row.names = F), na_s, names(na_s))
```

Comment: `lapply(1:length(na_s), function (x) write.csv(na_s[[x]],file = paste('./na_s_monthly/','na_',names (na_s[x]),'.csv',sep=""), row.names = F))` worked for me.

Comment: As it should.  The differences are that the code in my answer doesn't need to reference list indices within the function.